# swift 3 and CGContextEOClip

Tags: swift3, ios10

As I am converting my code to swift 3, I got this error:

```
error: 'CGContextEOClip' is unavailable: Use clip(using:)
                                CGContextEOClip(context!);
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
CoreGraphics.CGContextEOClip:2:13: note: 'CGContextEOClip' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
public func CGContextEOClip(_ c: CGContext?)
```

I have no idea how to use clip(using:) and I don't see any documentation relating to it.
Any ideas.
Thanks
Reza

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In swift3 `CGContextEOClip` and `CGContextClip` are now methods of `CGContext` type

```
let context = /*your context*/
context.clip(using: .evenOdd) // for CGContextEOClip
context.clip(using: .winding) // for CGContextClip
```

Comment: Yup. `CGContextEOClip` and `CGContextClip`, formerly two different functions for the two different fill rules possible when clipping, are unified into one method that takes a fill rule parameter.